# how to let jsontypeinfo return null on unknown type?

Tags: json, jackson

I have code like the following.

```
    @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "type", visible = true, defaultImpl = Default.class)
@JsonSubTypes({ 
    @Type(value = T1.class, name = "t1"), 
    @Type(value = T2.class, name = "t2"),}
) 
public abstract class T{
}
```

the other class may book like

```
class Foo{
T t;
T anotherT;
}
```

However, it will return an instance of Default if `type` in unknown.  If i did not specify defaultImp, jackson just throw an exception.

```
 Could not resolve type id 't3' into a subtype of T
```

I have `DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES` set to false already.

What I need is if type is not 't1' or 't2', just set the value to null, and continue parsing.
How can I do it?

Thanks

Comment: Interesting question, though I believe this would be difficult to implement since it would break deserialization. How do you expect the framework to handle deserializing `T` types that aren't `T1` or `T2`? Use the abstract class?

Comment: The problem only happen when json data has someting java code did not support. Java to json is always fine. I would just want the json parsing part fail silently. as FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES false did for unknown properties. The json is still valid json so the code should be able to continue.